# Windows: Screensharing over LAN

Tags: windows, lan, screen-sharing

What is the best way to connect two computers, offline, to screenshare from one computer to the other with good quality and get as little of a delay as possible?

What software should I use (has to be compatible with Windows)?

Can I connect an Ethernet cable to both computers and get good results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do it would be to connect both machines to a switch.

Alternatively you could create an ad hoc network by connecting the computers directly, which often requires a crossover cable instead of a regular Cat5 Ethernet cable.

Then if you just want to log into the other remotely, Remote Desktop should do the trick.

[Ad Hoc and Remote Desktop](http://www.ehow.com/how_8084766_set-connection-between-two-computers.html)

If you want the screen to be visible on both machines simultaneously, you should probably go for some kind of VNC software, such as [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The computers will need to be connected somehow.  Is it possible they are on the same wifi network or plugged into a switch?  If you can get them to ping each other, you can do sharing.

The easiest way on Windows will be Remote Desktop which is included with the OS.

[Remote Desktop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/)  (Windows)